Why is escape analysis not triggered in this particular example?
This is on open JDK 17, and all tests are run with 256MB memory. I've been testing escape analysis interactions with streams via some simple tests and ran into something interesting.
The code below appears to trigger escape analysis just fine (tested by adding -verbose:gc and running the code with and without -XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis. Runs without EA print GC activity while runs with EA do not)
public static int mapSum_boxed(){
        record TestObject(int i){};
        return IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000)
                .boxed()
                .map(x-> new TestObject(1))
                .mapToInt(x-> x.i())
                .sum();
    }

I'll note that this is not a benchmarking test. I simply call the function from the main method like so:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(mapSum_boxed());
    }

The outputs I get from the above call (with -verbose:gc flag) are:
> Task :org.example.Main.main()
[0.002s][info][gc] Using G1
1000000000

However, if I make the change below (add an extra map()), it fails to trigger escape analysis and I get GC activity printed to the console:
public static int mapSum_boxed(){
        record TestObject(int i){};
        return IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000)
                .boxed()
                .map(x-> 1) // <------- additional map() op
                .map(x-> new TestObject(1))
                .mapToInt(x-> x.i())
                .sum();
    }

The outputs this time are:
> Task :org.example.Main.main()
[0.002s][info][gc] Using G1
[0.053s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 23M->2M(246M) 1.398ms
[0.117s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 120M->2M(246M) 0.965ms
.... // many many more lines of GC
[6.530s][info][gc] GC(123) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 258M->2M(428M) 0.724ms
1000000000

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening ? I initially thought that the map(x->1) op was somehow converting the whole stream to Integer type but that seems unlikely...and that really should've happened at the boxed() stage anyways.

Are you running the code with JMH? Can you please provide the full code (including benchmark code) you are running? Please also include the exact JDK version including the vendor and OS/architecture. Are you using any other JVM arguments? Did you repeat your benchmark multiple times and get the same result?

@dan1st Fair questions. No this is not a JMH test. I'm simply calling the method from the main class with -verbose:gc flag on and am checking the results. I've added more info to my post. And yes, the results are consistent across multiple runs. I don't think OS/architecture is required here as JVM escape analysis is mostly independent of those but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Escape analysis isn't likely to kick in at all without time for the JVM to warm up -- say, in a benchmark run with JMH.

Please try to reproduce it with JMH and make sure to check the relevant (e.g. GC) logs in the measurement iteration (not warmup iterations). You can also view the generated assembly code if you want to (and if you happen to use GraalVM, there's a tool named IGV (ideal graph visualizer) which can be useful for debugging what happens in the JIT)
